# "return type mismatch in function" Error when creating a table with a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm quite new in SQL I'm trying to create a function returning a table, my code:

```
create or replace function ratios_table (datefrom date)
returns table(
    date_of_day date,
    counter integer
    )
as $$
    select
       "creationDate",
        count("interactionId")
    from "UserInteractions"
    where "creationDate" >= $1
    group by "creationDate"
$$
language SQL;
```

and I'm getting:

return type mismatch in function declared to return record

If I write it in plpgsql like this (Sure is bu...hit):

```
create or replace function ratios_table (datefrom date)
returns table(
    date_of_day date,
    counter integer
    )
as $$
    begin
        select
            "creationDate",
            count("interactionId")
        from "UserInteractions"
        where "creationDate" >= $1
        group by "creationDate"
    return end;
 $$
language plpgsql;
```

I get

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "return"
LINE 14:     return end;
```

I'd appreciate a lot your help and advise for a newbie. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `counter` value is the result of the `count()` function, which returns a `bigint`.

Declare `counter` as a `bigint` and it will work.

Note that the full error message would have pointed this

> ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return record
>   **DETAIL:  Final statement returns bigint instead of integer at column
>   2.**
>   CONTEXT:  SQL function "ratios_table"

I'm quite new in SQL I'm trying to create a function returning a table, my code:

```
create or replace function ratios_table (datefrom date)
returns table(
    date_of_day date,
    counter bigint
    )
as $$
    select
       "creationDate",
        count("interactionId")
    from "UserInteractions"
    where "creationDate" >= $1
    group by "creationDate"
$$
language SQL;
```